# False positive with circular type annotations across files in PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, circular-dependency, type-hinting

I have a moderately-sized project with many mutual relationships between objects across files. I'm currently learning about type annotations, and I'm trying to go through my project and add them wherever I can.

Sometimes, these type annotations have to refer to a class that has not yet been initialized, so I'm using `from __future__ import annotations` to lazily parse references. This does satisfy PyCharm's reference checker when the referenced class appears *in the same file*, but not in a *different* file, where it wants me to do a circular import to resolve the references.

## My test package: `Stem` and `Leaf`

I made a minimal test package to try out different solutions. In this test package, I'm trying to implement a simple "stem-leaf" relationship, where a `Stem` has a reference to many `leaves`, and each `Leaf` has a reference to its `stem`. To do this, I can either make `Leaf` import `Stem`, or `Stem` import `Leaf`. Both of those methods do satisfy PyCharm without type annotations, and they also do compile and run *with* type annotations, despite the fact that PyCharm's reference checker yells at me in both cases.

### Method 1: `Leaf` importing `Stem`

```py
"""test_circular_annotations/stem_then_leaf/stem.py"""
from __future__ import annotations


class Stem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.leaves: list[Leaf] = []

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Leaf:
        return self.leaves[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stem = Stem()
```

```py
"""test_circular_annotations/stem_then_leaf/leaf.py"""
from typing import Optional

from test_circular_annotations.stem_then_leaf.stem import Stem


class Leaf:
    def __init__(self, stem: Optional[Stem] = None) -> None:
        self.stem = stem

    @property
    def stem(self) -> Optional[Stem]:
        return self._stem_

    @stem.setter
    def stem(self, value: Optional[Stem]) -> None:
        self._stem_ = value
        if value and self not in value.leaves:
            value.leaves.append(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stem = Stem()
    leaf = Leaf(stem)
    assert stem is leaf.stem is stem[0].stem
```

#### What happens?

`stem.py` and `leaf.py` both execute successfully, but PyCharm flags the references to `Leaf` in `stem.py`, demanding that I import `Leaf` from `leaf.py` - which of course leads to an `ImportError` at runtime.

### Method 2: `Stem` importing `Leaf`

```py
"""test_circular_annotations/leaf_then_stem/stem.py"""
from test_circular_annotations.leaf_then_stem.leaf import Leaf


class Stem:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.leaves: list[Leaf] = []

    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> Leaf:
        return self.leaves[index]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    stem = Stem()
    leaf = Leaf(stem)
    assert stem is leaf.stem is stem[0].stem
```

```py
"""test_circular_annotations/leaf_then_stem/leaf.py"""
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import Optional


class Leaf:
    def __init__(self, stem: Optional[Stem] = None) -> None:
        self.stem = stem

    @property
    def stem(self) -> Optional[Stem]:
        return self._stem_

    @stem.setter
    def stem(self, value: Optional[Stem]) -> None:
        self._stem_ = value
        if value and self not in value.leaves:
            value.leaves.append(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    leaf = Leaf()
```

#### What happens?

Again, `stem.py` and `leaf.py` both execute successfully, but this time PyCharm flags the references to `Stem` in `leaf.py`.

## TL;DR

Here's what the project looks like in PyCharm:

[image]
The left side is with Leaf importing Stem; the right is with Stem importing Leaf. Again, all the modules do run properly, but each case sets off PyCharm's reference checker beforehand.

I feel like this is simply a bug in PyCharm, but just in case I'm posting this here first because it seems like a common issue that might just be a "me problem" with a canonical Python solution. I really don't want to have to put all collections of related objects in the same file - given the choice between that and omitting type annotations, I'd definitely take the latter.

What should I do? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Suppose you are defining a class "A" and you have a method "m" that receives an instance of "A". Since "m" is in "A" and class "A" is not defined yet, you can't write `def m(self, other_a: A) -> None:`. The proper way is to write `def m(self, other_a: "A") -> None:` (that is, use a string with the name of the type instead of the actual type). Maybe the same approach can be used in your case, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Yes, from my understanding this used to be true, but doing `from __future__ import annotations` allows you to just write `def m(self, other_a: A) -> None:`. The problem is not with Python itself, which again compiles and runs the code just fine, but with PyCharm, because it knows I'm trying to reference something that doesn't exist, but it doesn't know that Python doesn't care in this instance. Replacing the reference with a string of the reference doesn't change this in the IDE.

Comment: It is worth trying the "A" solution to see it pycharm accepts it. It might just not support the `from __future__ import annotations` option but still, work with the string option.

Comment: It doesn't work.